# GCC and -Wconversion

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer

Let's compile the following program:

```
int main()
{
    uint16_t data = 0;
    data |= uint16_t(std::round(3.14f));
    return 0;
}
```

with `g++ -Wconversion prog.cpp`

We'll get `warning: conversion to ‘uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may alter its value`, but I can't see implicit conversions here.

This kind of warnings should be muted by explicit casts, for example:

```
double d = 3.14;
float foo1 = d; // Warning
float foo2 = float(d); // No warning
float foo2 = static_cast<float>(d); // No warning
```

Is GCC right here or it's a bug?

Note that my snippet is minimal. For example, warning disappears in following cases:

- remove the `f` suffix from `3.14`, i.e. make it `double`
- use assignment instead of `|=`
- remove `std::round`
- cache rounding result: `const auto r = uint16_t(std::round(3.14f));`, then or-assign it to `data`.

Comment: Even more minimal example (that does not require headers and functions) would be `short data(0); data |= short(float{3.0f});`

Comment: False warning disappeared in GCC 10: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/brx4qGzYb

Answer (score 2):

> Is GCC right here or it's a bug?

Since the behavior does not match the expectation, I'd call it a bug.

From https://godbolt.org/z/aSj--7, it seems that in GCC's eye, `data |= uint16_t(std::round(3.14f))` is translated as

> `(void) (data = TARGET_EXPR <D.2364, (uint16_t) round (3.1400001049041748046875e+0)>;, data | NON_LVALUE_EXPR <D.2364>;)`

(`TARGET_EXPR` represents a temporary object. `D.2364` is an internal variable name.)

Translate GCC's internal language back to C++, and we'll get

```
data = (temp = (uint16_t) round (3.14e+0), data | temp)
```

Since the LHS of the comma expression does not affect the RHS, this should be as safe as `data = data | temp`. However, GCC warns at the former but not at the latter, which is very unlikely to be intentional. Thus I believe that it is an oversight of GCC maintainers.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is bogus.

According to [[over.built]/22](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over.built#22):

> For every triple (*L, VQ, R*), where *L* is an integral type, *VQ* is either volatile or empty, and *R* is a promoted integral type, there exist candidate operator functions of the form ...
>
> ```
> VQ L&   operator|=(VQ L&, R);
> ```

So we get a built-in `unsigned short operator |=(unsigned short&, unsigned int);`

There are no implicit conversions in the given expression

```
uint16_t data = 0;
data |= uint16_t(std::round(3.14f));
```