# How to disable warning from VS-Code GCC Compiler? (not use #pragma)

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working on VS-Code with C/C++ intellisense[gcc-arm]. When I do compile , The VS-Code show me hundred of warning like that:

*`Conversion from 'int' to u16_t{aka 'short unsigned int'} may change value [-Wconversion]`*

I do not want the VSCode show me those warning. **But I have no permission to edit the source code**. So, Is the any way to disable those warning by adding some arg to c_cpp_properties.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to [my own reference document here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world#additional-c-and-c-build-notes-ex-wgcc-or-clang-compilers), if you have access to the build flags, you can pass in `-Wno-conversion` to disable this warning at compile time.

From my document:

> #### Additional C and C++ build notes (ex: w/`gcc` or `clang` compilers):
>
> 1. Use `-Wwarning-name` to turn ON build warning "warning-name", and `-Wno-warning-name` to turn OFF build warning "warning-name". `-W` turns a warning ON, and `-Wno-` turns a warning OFF. Here's what gcc has to say about it (source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html; emphasis added):
>
>    > You can request many specific warnings with options beginning with `-W`, for example `-Wimplicit` to request warnings on implicit declarations. Each of these specific warning options also has a *negative form* beginning `-Wno-` to turn off warnings; for example, `-Wno-implicit`. This manual lists only one of the two forms, whichever is *not* the default.

Regarding Visual Studio Code, I do not use that IDE, but the `c_cpp_properties.json` file appears to have no ability to set build flags: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference.

The `tasks.json` file, however, does: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_build-helloworldcpp.

Here's their example:

> ```
> {
>   "version": "2.0.0",
>   "tasks": [
>     {
>       "type": "shell",
>       "label": "g++ build active file",
>       "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
>       "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
>       "options": {
>         "cwd": "/usr/bin"
>       },
>       "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
>       "group": {
>         "kind": "build",
>         "isDefault": true
>       }
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

So, it looks like you could add `-Wno-conversion` to the `args` list in the JSON file, like this:

```
"args": [
    "-Wno-conversion",
    "-g", 
    "${file}", 
    "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
],
```

### See also:

1. [How to include compiler flags in the Visual Studio Code debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173093/how-to-include-compiler-flags-in-the-visual-studio-code-debugger/57173879#57173879)

Comment: I'd like to add, that without code snippet and/or current configuration it's hard to tell, if that's a bogus warning, like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195424/gcc-and-wconversion